# Old version of Microsoft.NETCore.App cannot be found at release step

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an error in my build pipeline on Azure DevOps. The project called DevPortalWeb fails in the Publish step.

The project is upgraded to netcore3.1 (it was created with earlier version).

```
  DevPortalWeb -> C:\agent\_work\13\s\Application\DevPortalWeb\bin\release\netcoreapp3.1\DevPortalWeb.dll
  DevPortalWeb -> C:\agent\_work\13\s\Application\DevPortalWeb\bin\release\netcoreapp3.1\DevPortalWeb.Views.dll
  It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
  The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0-preview1-002111-00' (x64) was not found.
    - The following frameworks were found:
        3.1.22 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
        5.0.13 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
        6.0.1 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  
  You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
  
  The specified framework can be found at:
    - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=2.0.0-preview1-002111-00&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
C:\agent\_work\13\s\Application\DevPortalWeb\DevPortalWeb.csproj(45,3): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet bundle" exited with code -2147450730.
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

What could be a reason, that the build pipeline requires previous version of the framework? There is no reference to version '2.0.0-preview1-002111-00' in the project now.

Comment: I guess you need to install the SDK on your build server. You can find all the downloads here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet
Be aware that .netcore 2 is out of support, I suggest to upgrade the application to .netcore 3 oder .net6

Comment: Note, you can install .NET Core in your pipeline's own steps using the built-in UseDotNet@2 task. IME this task takes a few seconds of pipeline run time and frees you from having to maintain this in your agent machine separately.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that project was migrated from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET Core 3.1.
Several packages, including this one, do not target this version anymore. This is already included in version 3.0.

The migration documentation lists which packages are obsolete:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#remove-obsolete-package-references